# Ошибка в работе RelativeLayout в Android Studio

Tags: android

Здравствуйте! При старте приложения в эмуляторе не отображается метки android:label и android:icon, то есть после запуска эмулятора на начальной странице приложения вверху экрана отсутствует темная панель с иконкой (android:icon) и названием приложения (android:label), хотя оба параметра данного RelativeLayout прописаны в Манифесте. В чем может заключаться проблема?

Comment: Темная панель - Toolbar или ActionBar!

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте стиль приложения (res/values/style или в Манифесте). Не должно быть метки NoActionBar

Comment: стиль : style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

Comment: добавьте xml манифеста и содержание стиля. Если есть какой-то код в MainActivity и сам Layout. Так пока непонятно где может быть ошибка